# How to set a default value of X for balance Y at user Z

Tags: mysql

I have the following table;

```
CREATE TABLE `balance` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `wallet_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Now the default balance for all users for all "wallets" for when they first sign up is 0, which is what i want.

However how would i change it so that every user_id X receives 1000 amount of  of wallet_id 5 when they first sign up, without giving them 1000 of wallet_id 4/6/7/8 (all other wallet balances)?

edit:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
             Trigger: update_wallet_trigger
               Event: INSERT
               Table: users
           Statement: BEGIN

UPDATE balance
SET amount = amount + 1000
WHERE user_id = NEW.id AND wallet_id = 1;

END
              Timing: AFTER
             Created: 2018-04-22 13:48:37.13
            sql_mode: NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
             Definer: root@localhost
character_set_client: latin1
collation_connection: latin1_swedish_ci
  Database Collation: latin1_swedish_ci
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

My table currently looks like this:

```
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(10) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id   | int(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| amount    | double  | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| wallet_id | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

With your trigger, it still won't write any new balance/amounts.

Also if a new user is created in USERS, it gets a unique ID, (USER_ID), but that doesn't automatically get ported over to the balance table; the user_id doesn't exist there.

Only User_ID's that already have some sort of balance are listed in the balance table.

Comment: Honestly it might be easiest to handle this via a trigger.  Add a trigger which fires when a new user record gets written to your `user` table.  This trigger will bonus the wallet_id=5 type with 1000 dollars.

Comment: Or handle business logic from the application..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, a trigger would seem to fit your problem well.  You may create an after insert trigger on the user table which would fire after a new user record is inserted.  This trigger can add a bonus of 1000 to the balance for that user, for `wallet_id=5`.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER update_wallet_trigger
AFTER INSERT
   ON users FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

INSERT INTO balance (user_id, amount, wallet_id)
VALUES
    (NEW.id, 1000.0, 5)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE       -- upsert; add 1000 if the record already exists
    amount = amount + 1000.0;

END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

But, you may not even have to do this much.  From you application code, you may do the update, right after creating a new user record.

**Edit:**

I notice that you currently are using a default value of `NULL` for the `amount` column in the `balance` table.  Don't do this, because then adding anything to that default value would also result in `NULL`.  Instead, use a default value of zero:

```
CREATE TABLE balance (
    id int(10) NOT NULL,
    user_id int(10) NOT NULL,
    amount double DEFAULT 0.0,
    wallet_id int(11),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: So i added this trigger in the USERS table, created a new ID, but no balance was added. Not sure what went wrong. When i SHOW TRIGGERS\G -> See OP.

Comment: @Zacharin I think I see the problem.  You currently have the `amount` column defaulting to `NULL`.  This means that adding anything to it would just result also in `NULL`.  Change the default to zero and my trigger should work.

Comment: See my new answer. It still doesn't write any balance to the new user when the new user signs up.

Comment: @Zacharin Apologies, I think you should be doing an insert, not an update.  I assumed you already had records in `balance` for that user, which apparently is not the case.

Comment: I for a moment thought that the trigger would override the already existing balances for wallet_id = 5 for each user every time someone new signs up, but i don't think this is the case. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @Zacharin Maybe you want an upsert, q.v. my updated answer.